# Ubuntu won't detect mouse

Tags: 14.04, usb, mouse

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 through USB on my Samsung ATIV Book 2. When I connected my USB mouse, a Gigabyte M6880X Gaming Mouse, Ubuntu won't recognize it. This mouse works fine on other devices. The command

```
sudo rmmod psmouse ; sudo modprobe psmouse
```

only restarts the trackpad.

`lsusb` output shows:

```
Bus 001 Device 009: ID 0c45:64e0 Microdia 
Bus 001 Device 010: ID 0cf3:3004 Atheros Communications, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

whether the mouse is plugged in, or not. Why can't Ubuntu detect my mouse?

Comment: What does lsusb output show?

Comment: If you want to know what exactly you have installed, see `/var/log/apt/history.log`.

Comment: wintermute, I have added more info above in the original post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I've gotten another mouse. Seems like Gigabyte mouses doesn't play well with the Linux kernel.

Thanks to everyone who helped me diagnose the issue.

Answer (score 3):

This command worked for me (note the extra `proto=` argument)

```
sudo modprobe -r psmouse
sudo modprobe psmouse proto=imps
```

Comment: It didn't work in my case. :-(

Comment: Me neither (adding some more characters here to get past the "5 more to go" message).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like (re)installing software or loading modules isn't going to help because the mouse isn't even seen by `lsusb`. Things I'd try:

- Try plugging the mouse in other USB ports on the same laptop
- Try plugging some other mouse instead of this one in the same USB port
- Try plugging some other device in the same USB port (e.g. a flash drive)
- Try booting Ubuntu liveUSB and checking if the mouse works there

Comment: Tried the first... All the USB ports still show the same 'lsusb' output.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not have another mouse to test on, however I remember briefly that on day one, a wireless mouse via USB actually worked.

Comment: And yes, the USB port is NOT dead.

Comment: Tried the last measure... And the liveUSB will not recognize the USB mouse... Maybe since it's a gaming mouse, and it needs awesomesauce drivers?

Comment: That's really strange. What system was there before? You can also try other Linux LiveUSB, or even an unofficial Windows one to see if the problem persists.

Comment: The BIOS won't even recognize the mouse, however it works in Windows. What the..